# What happen with MFC CString in " CStringA csA = CStringW("hello", 5);"

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

It does compiled. But I do not think it should. It compile both in VS2008 and VS2013.

[image: The pic is VS2013]

I Add a picture to show it does compile. but I am really confused at this. The picture is VS2013.

Comment: It *doesn't* compile in VS2013 for me. Nor in VS2012, for that matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why shouldn't it compile? There's explicit code in CString to handle exactly such unicode-to-ascii conversions:

```
CStringT& operator=(_In_opt_z_ PCYSTR pszSrc)
{
    ...
    PXSTR pszBuffer = GetBuffer( nDestLength );
    StringTraits::ConvertToBaseType( pszBuffer, nDestLength, pszSrc);
    ...
}
```

and internally (note the explicit LPSTR and LPCWSTR in the signature):

```
    static void __cdecl ConvertToBaseType(
    _Out_writes_(nDestLength) LPSTR pszDest,
    _In_ int nDestLength,
    _In_ LPCWSTR pszSrc,
    _In_ int nSrcLength = -1) throw()
{
    // nLen is in XCHARs
    ::WideCharToMultiByte( _AtlGetConversionACP(), 0, pszSrc, nSrcLength, pszDest, nDestLength, NULL, NULL );
}
```

You can step into it from the debugger.